# Cannot compile and run code from a shared folder between PopOS and Windows

Tags: python, c, linux, networking, compiler-errors

I have a `PopOs` PC accessing my `Windows` PC network. On my shared folder I want to compile and run `.c` files and run `.py` files. But the following error appears

When I try to run the `gdb` debugger on `VS Code` on `PopOS`:

```
launch:program '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.xx.x',share=${SHARED FILE PATH ON NETWORK}' does not exist
```

Similar issue is shown for `python` files too.

I understand that the compiled version is OS depended and might not be able to run cross platform. But I only want to compile and run the code on the`PopOS` PC and use the `Windows` PC to just edit the code.

Comment: What is `share=${SHARED FILE PATH ON NETWORK}`?

Comment: its the path to the network file, where the file is located on the network. It can vary, to make it more clear I put it as a variable.